# Functional Programming: Implement map on a PrototypePassed JavaScript

Tags: javascript, foreach, callback, prototype

I was doing that FreeCodeCamp's exercise and i don't get the logic and the code. Here is it:

```
// the global Array
var s = [23, 65, 98, 5];

Array.prototype.myMap = function(callback) {
  var newArray = [];
  // Add your code below this line
  this.forEach(a => newArray.push(callback(a)));
  // Add your code above this line
  return newArray;
};

var new_s = s.myMap(function(item) {
  return item * 2;
});
```

Could anyone help me and explain it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will output to `new_s` an array containing the values of `s` x 2

Let's review this :

```js
Array.prototype.myMap = function(callback) { ... }
```

- `myMap` is a function that applies to arrays (`Array.prototype`)
- This function has an argument named `callback`. This argument will be a function (even if here you still can only guess from the name of the argument ;)

```js
  var newArray = [];
  // Add your code below this line
  this.forEach(a => newArray.push(callback(a)));
  // Add your code above this line
  return newArray;
```

- Loop through all the values of `this` (the array to which you will apply `myMap`)
- Apply the function referenced by `callback` to each value
- Add the result of the `callback` function to the `newArray` array
- Return the result array

Finally :

```js
var new_s = s.myMap(function(item) {
  return item * 2;
});
```

- Apply the `myMap` function to `s` with the `callback` function being a function that will return, for a value of `s`, `2 * s`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
Array.prototype.myMap = function(callback) {

  const newArray = [];

   this.forEach((element, index, array) => newArray.push(callback(element, index, array)))

  return newArray;

};
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer. The question was asking about an explanation of a code that already exists. This answer provides some other code without any explanation instead of explaining the code the asker was wondering about.